# How to get all possible methods that can be called on a variable in js (including non object varibles like a number)

Tags: javascript, debugging, runtime

For debugging purposes, I would like to know (in runtime) all possible methods that I can call on a specific js variable.

This can be done in Chrome console (and others), but I like a javascript method that gives me an array with strings of the names of all methods that can be called on a variable.

If you use "for..in" or Object.keys, we dont get all method!
(If you call these on a variable containing a number, it doesn't include methods defined in Number.prototype!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay for others who have same problem I ended up writing this method.

```
var getKeys = function(obj){
    var keys = [], k;
    if (typeof obj !== "object" && typeof obj !== "function" || obj === null) {
        //primitive
    }else{
        for (k in obj){
            if(keys.indexOf(k) === -1){
                keys.push(k);           
            }
        }
    } 
    var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
    var prototype_keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window[type].prototype);
    for (k = 0; k<prototype_keys.length;k++){
        if(keys.indexOf(prototype_keys[k]) === -1){
            keys.push(prototype_keys[k]);
        }
    }
    return keys;
};
```

Comment: if its an Object it get all properties of the object, then add (concat) all properties of the Object.prototype. If it a primitive it simple return all properties of the primities corresponding prototype (like Number.prototype for i number)

Comment: This also gets all properties, so if you want only methods you need to filter the array so you only get functions...